# sencha app build, how to detect Closure compiler errors in CI?

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I performed an experiment with sencha cmd version v7.0.0.40:
I made some syntax errors in our ExtJs project sources. Then I ran `sencha app build`.
There were many errors (like `C2001: Closure Compiler Error...`), but sencha cmd returned 0.

When I run `sencha app build some abra cadabra` - it returns 1 as expected.

There is a lonely post without answer on sencha forums:
https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?262219-Sencha-Cmd-Error-Codes

So what is the standard way to detect `sencha app build` build errors in CI?
Should I just parse its stderr/stdout or what?
If it is important, I am on linux.

---

UPD:
I noticed that `sencha --strict app build` returns error codes if there were warnings or errors and writes something like
`[WRN] Exiting with code 22, 176 warnings and 8 errors` as the last string in stdout.
So for now I am going to use `--strict` and parse this last string.
If somebody has easier solution - let me know, please.

---

UPD2:
Sencha cmd 7.0+ has a config option for warnings level.
https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/7.0.0/guides/whats_new_cmd70.html

So we decided to remove all warnings and check return code from `sencha --strict app build`.

---

Answer (score 0):

To detect error reason you can use flag -D (debug)

```
sencha -D app build
```